# Higher-kinded interfaces with "implements" restriction

Tags: c#, higher-kinded-types

I have a specific problem where I have an interface `IA` that has a method `Foo` that returns another interface `IB`. I want to be able to have two interfaces `IA1` (that implements `IA`) and `IB1` (that implements `IB`), and have `IA.Foo` return `IB1`. I'd like for this to happen with any other interface that implements `IA` (for example, some `IA2`).

I think the only possible way to do this is via higher-order-types, which would look like the "solution" below (which is not valid C#):

```
public interface IA<M> where M<> : IB<>
{
    M<T> Foo1<T>(T val);
    M<T> Foo2<T>();
}

public interface IB<T>
{
    T Bar();
}

public interface IA1 : IA<IB1> {}

public interface IB1<T> : IB<T>
{
    void Bar1();
}

public interface IA2 : IA<IB2> {}

public interface IB2<T> : IB<T>
{
    void Bar2(T val);
}

public void MyFunc()
{
    IA1 myA1 = GetMyA1();
    IB1<int> myB1Int = myA1.Foo1<int>(2);
    int myB1IntBar = myB1Int.Bar();
    myB1Int.Bar1();
    IB1<string> myB1String = myA1.Foo2<string>();
    string myB1StringBar = myB1String.Bar();

    IA2 myA2 = GetMyA2();
    IB2<string> myB2 = myA2.Foo1<string>("Hello World");
    string myB2StringBar = myB2.Bar();
    myB2.Bar2("Value");
}
```

Is there a way to simulate this in C#?

Answer (score 4):

I think that what you're looking for is the concept of Covariance. You can find some explanations online for it. I'll point you to some .NET documentation, which I think are relevant to this question but that on their own may not be the best for explaining the concept of covariance.

[How to define an interface with a covariant type parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx#DefiningVariantTypeParameters)

> A covariant type parameter is marked with the out keyword (Out keyword
>   in Visual Basic, + for the MSIL Assembler). You can use a covariant
>   type parameter as the return value of a method that belongs to an
>   interface, or as the return type of a delegate.

[The `out` keyword on generic type parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)

> An interface that has a covariant type parameter enables its methods
>   to return more derived types than those specified by the type
>   parameter.

I've revised your code using the `out` keyword. Take a look and see if this is what you had in mind:

```
public interface IA<T, out M> where M : IB<T>
{
    M Foo(T val);
}

public interface IB<T>
{
    void Bar();
}

public interface IA1<T> : IA<T, IB1<T>> {}

public interface IB1<T> : IB<T>
{
    void Bar1();
}

public interface IA2<T> : IA<T, IB2<T>> {}

public interface IB2<T> : IB<T>
{
    void Bar2();
}

public void MyFunc()
{
    IA1<int> myA1 = GetMyA1();
    IB1<int> myB1 = myA1.Foo(2);
    myB1.Bar();
    myB1.Bar1();

    IA2<string> myA2 = GetMyA2();
    IB2<string> myB2 = myA2.Foo("Hello World");
    myB2.Bar();
    myB2.Bar2();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response, but the variable `T` is not a parameter of `IA`, but of `Foo` instead (and indeed, it actually has several other methods like `Foo` with other type parameters). I'll update the question to show it more clearly

Comment: @gonzaw I get what you're trying to do, but I don't *think* it's syntactically possible in C#. I think that you need to provide type parameters for the generic types within a "where" type constraint. It might be that the approach can be refactored to better achieve what you really want, though.